# How to capture many to many field values via get_initial command

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am slowly progressing in my django journey, but this one has me stumped.  I am trying to populate a CreateView with a different model via a copy command using the get_initial override.  All of the attributes copy as I would expect with the exception of the ManytoMany fields.  I've researched this topic most of today, and found the following which is very close to what I'm trying to figure out [KeyError: 'manager' in django get_initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366436/keyerror-manager-in-django-get-initial).

My View...

```
class BookView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Book 
    template_name = 'book/titles.html'
    form_class = BookForm

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(BookView, self).get_initial()
    author = author.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    initial = author.__dict__.copy()
    initial.update({              
            "author": author.name,
       }}  

    for field in self.form_class.base_fields.items():
        value = getattr(self.get_object(), field)
        if field == 'author':
            value = self.get_object().author.all()
        initial.update({field: value})
    return initial
```

I incorporated the suggested change based on the issue that I found on SO, but I still am getting a 'manager" KeyError.  I am ultimately trying to populate the manytomanyfield in my model and then save the values, but to no avail.  Any suggests are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a difference a day makes....

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(BookView, self).get_initial()
    author = author.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    initial = author.__dict__.copy()
    initial.update({              
            "author": author.name.all(),
       }}  
    return initial
```

I added a .all() after the reference to the manytomanyfield in my initial get and also update the form to get the field in question.  Much cleaner than a few hacks I kinda got working along the way.